# Weird struct access errors

Tags: c++, struct

Basically I have this code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

    struct foo{
        string *question;
        //other elements
    };

    int main(){
        foo *q;
        foo *q2;
        q->question = new string("This is a question"); 
        //q2->question = new string("another question");
    }
```

and when I uncomment `q2->question = new string("another question");` it errors and I have no idea why.

**Update:**
the error is a windows message saying the program has stopped working and it prints `Process exited with return value 3221225477`

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: Process exited with return value 3221225477

Comment: You're not initializing those pointers!

Comment: I would advise you to turn up your warning level: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/19708e563bc6b00a. Shame nothing is said about the missing header.

Comment: Why then does it compile with one line in but not both?

Comment: Run your program through a _debugger_.

Comment: @chris: In C++11, `iostream` almost certainly includes `string`.

Comment: @Gibby, It does compile with both, but crashes in your case.

Comment: Thank you this was dumb of me, it wont let me accept an answer yet but it is answered.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, Oh? I swear that recently, some implementations have *stopped* including `<string>` in `<iostream>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `q` and `q2` pointers are uninitialized. You're trying to access memory which you haven't allocated. As a short term fix:

```
int main(){
    foo *q = new foo;
    foo *q2 = new foo;
    q->question = new string("This is a question"); 
    q2->question = new string("another question");

    // don't forget to release the memory you allocate!
    delete q->question;
    delete q2->question;
    delete q;
    delete q2;

}
```

A better solution in this case is not to use pointers... there's absolutely no need. Use the stack, and you don't need to deal with pointers, and no need to deallocate.

```
int main(){
    string q1 = "This is a question";
    string q2 = "another question";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foo *q;
foo *q2;
```

You're getting Undefined Behavior when using indirection on these pointers because these pointers have not been initialized (i.e. they are not pointing to a valid address).

You need to have them point to an object:

```
foo* q  = new foo();
foo* q2 = new foo();

// don't forget to delete
```

or just use stack-allocation:

```
foo q;
foo q2;

q.question = "This is a question";
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't allocate memory for `q` and `q2`.

Replace

```
foo *q;
foo *q2;
```

with

```
foo *q = new foo();
foo *q2 = new foo();
```

At the end, delete all created objects:

```
delete q->question;
delete q;
delete q2->question;
delete q2;
```